# Reducing spaces

Tags: line-breaking

I have a paragraph in itemize.

The paragraph is a long one as as a result it moves to a new line. However, I want to reduce the interline space. I have used \baselineskip but it is making the text too compact. How can i reduce the normal spacing to say 4mm?

Please check the exception path thing.
[image]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to clarify the question. How is the question related to LaTeX3?

Comment: If the average word length is four characters and all are narrow, say 3pt, you need at least 600pt, that is 21cm or 8.3in. So it's very unlikely that fifty words can be accommodated on a single line.

Comment: Do you mean that your document uses, say, `onehalfspacing` and you want your itemize environment to have single spacing?

Comment: The text appear as:
Some text
<unwanted space>
Continuation of text
<unwanted space>
Remaining space

Comment: I have tried baselineskip. So, it does not add inter-line space but it is making it too compact. how can i make the interline space say, 4mm?

Comment: I would not change the layout for sake of trying to fit the text. Your readers will notice this. Furthermore, once you start doing this, you'll be doing this all the time. The resulting document won't look nice. I'd try to reformulate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm taking an educated guess that (i) your document uses one-and-one-half spacing or even double spacing and (ii) you want to use single-spacing in environments such as `enumerate`. You also don't specify *how* you've gone about implementing the wider spacing, so I'll assume that you do so by loading the `setspace` package and issuing the command `\onehalfspacing` (or `\doublespacing`). If these guesses are *not* correct, please indicate what is, in fact, going on in your document.

If these guesses are correct, you could issue the following two commands in the preamble to have single-spacing be in effect in all `enumerate` environments:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \AtBeginEnvironment macro
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\singlespacing}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the `singlespacing` environment should apply to just one particular `enumerate` environment instead of all of them, you could still load the `setspace` package and simply issue the command `\singlespacing` immediately after the applicable `\begin{enumerate}` statement.

Comment: Thanks lot! i added use package setspace and entered \singlespacing in the enumerate. It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nis - Glad you found the answer helpful. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept answers you find solve the issue you've raised. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

Turning the code snippet to a full example I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item I have a text here. I want to reduce the interline space out here. I
want it to be little compact. Please help me.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

I cannot see any unusual excessive spacing. Any reduced `\baselineskip` would make it very ugly.